# DelimitedFiles.readdlm(source, ....) modifies source, is that really intended and where in the documentation/definition is this explained?

Tags: julia

surprised to find that `DelimitedFiles.readdlm(source, ...)` changes the `source` input parameter. surprised because Ι could find no indication hereof in the official documentation https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/DelimitedFiles/index.html. is this just a standard assumption about mutability in julia? i thought that `somefunction` that might change an input parameter would indicate this with `somefunction!` (adding `!` to the function name)?

Ι used the function as follows:

```
out = DelimitedFiles.readdlm(source,',',header=true)
```

before the call, source has type `Array{UInt8,1}` and has several elements. after the call, out has type `Tuple{Array{Any,2},Array{AbstractString,2}}`, source has type `Array{UInt8,1}` (unchanged) and source is empty (changed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `String(vec::Vector{UInt8})` does not perform a copy but takes ownership of `vec` (and mutates it).

For now you should write:

```
out = DelimitedFiles.readdlm(copy(source),',',header=true)
```

I have asked a question [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/16731#issuecomment-499467106) to clarify what is the intended target behavior (copying or non-copying).

Comment: many thx!! it would be nice for the documentation to be absolutely clear on this. for any function in any package;-)

Comment: This was a bug and will be fixed and backported. See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/32255. Thank you for reporting this.